# Phantomjs 2.0.1 and woff

Tags: phantomjs, woff

Neither current windows nor linux binary (build on Ubuntu 14.04 with http://phantomjs.org/build.html) accept woff-fonts (via @font-face in CSS). Is there some kind of magic trick to switch woff support on? SVG and TTF font are accepted, but (i used ProcMon on widows) pantomjs do not make any attempts to search files with .woff extension on my system.

I saw some messages from people claimed they got phantomjs2 working with woff, so does anybody know the truth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WOFF v1 support will be enabled in PhantomJS v2.1](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12927). For the time being, you may use PhantomJS 1.9.x or compile it yourself.

There are two pull requests that accomplish this at the moment [1](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/12898) and [2](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/12856).

PhantomJS 2 supports ttf and svg fonts, so it is advisable to try a multi-font-type approach.